# Using threads in C. Getting unexpected results

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I am just new to threads in C.
So starting with the very basics.
I am just trying to create threads and using mutual exclusion on them.
I have declared three function and creating 3 threads for them but every time I execute my program not all three processes get executed all the time

Please give a solution to this.

Comment: You are not calling `pthread_join` correctly, look at the man page.

Comment: I've rolled back your recent edit, which essentially destroyed the question.

Comment: Edited the question and deleted the code as this is an aasignment from my class and I don,t want it get copied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the thread object, in `pthread_join()`, See updated line#35,38,41.

The definition of the function is `int pthread_join(pthread_t thread, void **retval);`

This shall help.

```
 34     thread1=pthread_create(&trd1,NULL,process1,(void *)nargs1);
 35     pthread_join(trd1, NULL);
 36
 37     thread2=pthread_create(&trd2,NULL,process2,(void *)nargs2);
 38     pthread_join(trd2, NULL);
 39
 40     thread3=pthread_create(&trd3,NULL,process3,(void *)nargs3);
 41     pthread_join(trd3, NULL);
```

Comment: Still not getting the desired output.
Although if i put sleep before the return of the main function It works.
Can anybody suggest why above code is not working as join does the same thing of waiting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked.Was joining the threads with wrong parameters.